# Is there a way to refactor these constructors?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

So I have an object, lets call it myObject

Here are the constructors to my object

```java
private static class myObject {
        public myObject(int argA) {
            this.argA = argA;
        }

        public myObject(int argA, boolean argB) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argB = argB;
        }

        public myObject(int argA, int argC, int argD) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argC = argC;
            this.argD = argD;
        }

        public myObject(int argA, String argE) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argE = argE;
        }


        public int argA = 1;
        public boolean argB;
        public int argC = 4;
        public int argD = 5;
        public String argE;
```

Basically I have default values and the constructor overrides these default values when required.
This makes it very clean in the code when I call these constructors I can just

```java
myObject newObject = new myObject(4);
```

However, an API is giving me a list of arguments to create this object with

```java
List objectParams1 = Arrays.asList(1,3,4)
List objectParams2 = Arrays.asList(1,false)
List objectParams3 = Arrays.asList(1,"tomato")
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters1 = ?;
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters2 = ?;
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters3 = ?;
```

Creating this object with a list of params is very difficult as it does not know which constructor to use. Is the builder method the way to go with this? However this will make code base much larger as I have to call this constructor ~100 times..

```java
myObject objectA = myObject.builder().withargA(4).withArgB(true).build();
```

Comment: Btw Java class names start with uppercase variables (`MyObject`). It's very confusing otherwise, especially when calling static methods

Comment: I would strongly prefer the builder method in this scenario.  Yes, it's longer, but it's astronomically easier to read when you don't have to memorize what combination of types refers to what combination of arguments.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't think you need a builder here. Just a factory method that tests the size of the list and the types (to distinguish the int boolean/int String cases).

Comment: I always prefer readability over any other concerns. Java already has a lot of boilerplate code. Not sure how adding a couple of more make any difference? You can always use `lombok` to minimise boilerplate code. `@Builder` is a simple annotation for generating builders.

Comment: @PLfan666 I am confused as to how you would be able to get from the `List objectParams1` to the static calls to the builder. Are you really saying you are handed a List of objects? If so, why would refactoring the constructors or using a builder help?

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm just looking for the best way to instantiate this object given a list of arguments. The factoryt method to test the sizes and types seems to work but it looks clunky

Comment: @PLfan666 I agree, it is clunky, but only inside that method. The call site is quite clean, far cleaner than any way I can think of to decide "I need to call X method on the builder". The real source of the clunkiness is having to deal with this List.

Comment: @AndyTurner would it be easier if I was given a hashmap of arguments?

{ ArgA : 4, ArgB: true, ... } and combine this with a builder class? If so, how would I create the object given this map since the keys to maps are strings.

Comment: @PLfan666 that would be more conducive to using a builder.

Answer (score 2):

You only have four cases, so it's quite easy to write a static factory method:

```
static myObject create(List<?> args) {
  int argA = (int) args.get(0);
  switch (args.size()) {
    case 1:
      return new myObject(argA);
    case 2:
      if (args.get(1) instanceof Boolean) {
        return new myObject(argA, (boolean) args.get(1)) 
      }
      return new myObject(argA, (String) args.get(1));
    case 3:
        return new myObject(argA, (int) args.get(1), (int) args.get(2));
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

Then:

```
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters1 = create(objectParams1);
// etc.
```

This is pretty gross (it can fail in all sorts of ways at runtime, if the list has the wrong number of elements, or elements of the wrong type, or the boxed primitive elements are null), but I don't really see what other choice you have if the parameters come from a List.

---

An alternative without doing the explicit checking would be to use reflection to obtain a constructor:

```
Class<?>[] classes =
    args.stream()
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .map(YourClass::unboxedClass)
        .toArray(Class<?>[]::new);
```

where `unboxedClass` is a method which translates `Integer.class` and `Boolean.class` into `int.class` and `boolean.class`. Then:

```
return myObject.getClass().getConstructor(classes).newInstance(args);
```

(and handle all the checked exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

Not claiming this is the correct way but you could set all values in a main constructor, and then call the main constructor from constructors defined with other signatures using the `this` keyword:

The only thing to really notice here is that I've set some "default" values where no value is provided in the varying constructors.

```
private static class myObject {

    public int argA = 1;
    public boolean argB;
    public int argC = 4;
    public int argD = 5;
    public String argE;

    public myObject(int argA, boolean argB, int argC, int argD, String argE) {
        this.argA = argA;
        this.argB = argB;
        this.argC = argC;
        this.argD = argD;
        this.argE = argE;
    }

    public myObject(int argA) {
        this(argA, false, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public myObject(int argA, boolean argB) {
        this(argA, argB, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public myObject(int argA, int argC, int argD) {
        this(argA, false, argC,  argD, null);
    }

    public myObject(int argA, String argE) {
        this(argA, false, 0, 0, argE);
    }
}
```

If you're going to add a lot of these types of constructors, you may end up with signature clashes which won't work. Builder is good when you need to specify a bunch of optional parameters that vary + some that are mandatory. Relatively simple to implement as every method returns itself (`this`), and you just update the fields as necessary, then finally call `.build()` to create the object.

Comment: But, given a List containing the args, how do you call one of these constructors?

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor that takes all arguments (make it private if you want) and call that one from all others. The arguments you don't have will be set to their default values:

```
private static class MyObject {

    private boolean b;
    private int a, c, d;
    private String e;

    private MyObject(int a, boolean b, int c, int d, String e) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }

    public MyObject(int a, int c, int d) {
        this(a, false, c, d, null);
    }

    public MyObject(int a, boolean b) {
        this(a, b, 3, 4, null);
    }

    public MyObject(int a, String e) {
        this(a, false, 3, 4, e);
    }

}
```

There are however a few downsides to this:

1. It harms readability and can confuse you.
2. If you want to change the default values for certain arguments, you'll have to remember to change them in every constructor. You can work around this by storing the defaults in `static final` variables, but still not ideal.

You should also consider naming your variables differently, as `a, b, c, d and e` or `argA, argB, argC, argD, argE` don't really convey much information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builder pattern here if you wish. This may look ugly and boilerplate-y, but it means you don't need a separate constructor for each case, and it will allow you to chain your builder, since each instance method in `Builder` returns `this`. It also doesn't look too bad if you keep the method names short.

You can use it like this (notice that you can leave out c or any other field because the defaults are set in the `Builder` class):

```
MyObject object = 
  new Builder()
    .a(4)
    .b(true)
    .d(0)
    .e("56")
    .build();
```

The modified `MyObject` class:

```
class MyObject {
  public int a;
  public boolean b;
  public int c;
  public int d;
  public String e;

  public MyObject(int a, boolean b, int c, int d, String e) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
  }
}
```

The `Builder` class

```
class Builder {
  public int a = 1;
  public boolean b;
  public int c = 4;
  public int d = 5;
  public String e;

  public Builder a(int a) {
    this.a = a;
    return this;
  }

  public Builder b(boolean b) {
    this.b = b;
    return this;
  }

  public Builder c(int c) {
    this.c = c;
    return this;
  }

  public Builder d(int d) {
    this.d = d;
    return this;
  }

  public Builder e(String e) {
    this.e = e;
    return this;
  }

  public MyObject build() {
    return new MyObject(a, b, c, d, e);
  }
}
```

Another way to implement the builder, with a `Map` and casting afterwards. It's typesafe, but the class above with fields is probably better because it doesn't involve unnecessary boxing and unboxing with primitives.

```
class Builder {

  private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

  {
    map.put("a", 1);
    map.put("b", false);
    map.put("c", 4);
    map.put("d", 5);
    map.put("e", null);
  }

  public Builder a(int a) {
    map.put("a", a);
    return this;
  }

  public Builder b(boolean b) {
    map.put("b", b);
    return this;
  }

  public Builder c(int c) {
    map.put("c", c);
    return this;
  }

  public Builder d(int d) {
    map.put("d", d);
    return this;
  }

  public Builder e(String e) {
    map.put("e", e);
    return this;
  }

  public MyObject build() {
    return new MyObject(
      (Integer) map.get("a"), 
      (Boolean) map.get("b"), 
      (Integer) map.get("c"), 
      (Integer) map.get("d"), 
      (String) map.get("e"));
  }
}
```